# expect loop / expect_out(buffer) issue

Tags: for-loop, expect

i'm new to expect. trying to write a script for cisco router that takes a list of interfaces as input, iterates over each interface, runs a command, saves output, counts number of lines in output and carries out if/else statements based on count.

I've searched on forums and pieced together the following script based on what other users have advised:

Just pasting code for the loop here for now:

```
foreach int $interfaces {

    match_max 20000
    send_user "\n"
    send_user "====== Checking $int ======\n"
    send_user "\n"


    set capture [open output2 w]
    expect "#"
    send "show policy-map $int out\n"
    sleep 1
    expect "#"
    set output $expect_out(buffer)
    puts $capture $output
    close $capture
    set capture 0

    send_user "\n\n---------- $expect_out(buffer) ------------\n\n"
    set count 0
    set count [exec cat output2 | wc -l]
    send_user "\n=========== $int $count ===========\n"

    if {$count<3} {
    puts "Service policy on ! $ip ! $int ! is not working"
    } else {
    puts "Service policy on ! $ip ! $int is working"
    }

    exec echo > output2
```

}

However, when I run the script the file output2 and expect_out(buffer) always has just one character '#'. So i don't get the required results. For some reason, expect_out(buffer) isn't catching output of the command 'show policy-map $int out' and writing it to the file. I am guessing there's a fundamental coding mistake here in terms of the loop structure.

Help would be much appreciated!

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you again for your support. I found the issue. There was a '#' preceding the one i was interested in. Changed pattern match and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

First off, read this book for expect learning: [Exploring Expect](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565920903.do)

From above book:

> All of the matched characters plus the characters that came earlier
>   but did not match are stored in a variable called expect_out(buffer).

In this case, it is nothing but your pattern which you are expecting and it is `#`. So what you see it right.

Now, for your requirement, please refer [How to access the result of a remote command in Expect](http://wiki.tcl.tk/2958). This link has the necessary explanation for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You are right, I am matching '#', but I am also expecting to see the result of the command before '#' to be in expect_out(buffer). But it is only showing the matched pattern.

Comment: Thank you again for your support. I found the issue. There was a '#' preceding the one i was interested in. Changed pattern match and now it works.